# Django - Variable cached with "with" template tag isn't evaluated

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm following along [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-minimal-form), and I have a form like this:

```html
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset>
    <legend><h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1></legend>
    {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

I figured, since there are multiple instances of `"choice{{ forloop.counter }}"`, I can cache it with [`with` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with) and use it as a variable. But as you can see, the variable [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) inside the `with` template tag isn't evaluated.

[image: not expected]

The expected result was this:

[image: expected result]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable using `{{ }}` cannot be used inside [**{% %}Built-in tag[Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-tag-reference) but we can use the `variable` inside `{% %}` if it is already available in the template. So we have to get the value before and we can set that value using [**with[Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with). But the value you are getting is dynamic with every loop you get new value with `{{forloop.counter}}` and the same thing we cannot use `{{ }}` inside `{% %}`.So you can concatenate the values differently i.e. `{{forloop.counter}}` and `choice`.
For `concatenate` we can use [**add Built-in filter[Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add) as documented

> Adds the argument to the value. This filter will first try to **coerce both values to integers**. If this fails, it’ll attempt to add the values together anyway. This will work on some data types (strings, list, etc.) and fail on others.

But the problem with `add` is  as **`Warned`** as

> **`Strings that can be coerced to integers will be summed, not concatenated,`**

So we have to convert the `{{forloop.counter}}` to string first before concatenation and we can use [**stringformat[Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat) for that and store the value and use that value as

```
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    {% with counter=forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" %} 
    {% with choice_id="choice"|add:counter %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id={{choice_id}} value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for={{choice_id}}>{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```